# Simple linked list with random values

Tags: c, list, linked-list

Okay so here's the task: Implement a list with 25 ordered random integers between 0 and 100.

My approach: get 25 numbers in an array, order the array and create the list with the array elements.

```
#include <conio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node{
    int data;
    struct Node *next;
};

int main()
{
    struct Node *p=NULL;
    struct Node *q=NULL;
    int j,i,aux,n,v[25];

    for (i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        v[i]=rand()%100;
    }

    for (i=0;i<25;i++)
    {
        for (j=1;j<25;j++)
        {
            if (v[i]>v[j])
            {
                aux=v[i];
                v[i]=v[j];
                v[j]=v[i];
            }
        }
    }

    q=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    q->data=v[0];
    q->next=NULL;

    for (i=1;i<25;i++)
    {
        p=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        q->next=p;
        p->data=v[i];
        p->next=NULL;
        q=p;
    }

    while (p)
    {
        printf("%d ",p->data);
        p=p->next;
    }

}
```

**Output: 0.**

**Can you guys figure out what I did wrong ?**

Comment: You didn't seed `rand()` for one, and you're not returning a value from `main()`, and you're typecasting the result of `malloc()`...

Comment: You are also not using `aux=v[i]`. You set `v[i]=v[j]` and then `v[j]=v[i]` in your sort loop. You should set `v[j]=aux` to complete the bubble swap.

Comment: @Mike, not seeding `rand()` means it will default to the seed value of 1. So he will always get identical results on each run of his program.

Comment: What about using a single-stepping through the program in a debugger?

Comment: @StarPilot - Yes... and IMO that's a problem when you want `"a list random integers"` as he mentions.

Comment: Where do you save the head of your linked array?

Comment: @Mike, yes, that is a problem in "production" mode, but it is desirable in debug mode. Makes it easy to know what values are popping out of your `rand()` so you know what you should be seeing and what to expect every run.

Comment: If this is/was a homework assignment then loading an array of 25 rand-vals, sorting it, then using it as the basis for a feeder for a linked list is probably not what your prof had in mind. More likely, he wants you to either merge-sort (or some other algorithm) the list after building it with initial random data, or use insertion-sort (or similar algorithm) to sort it *while* the random data is added. Doing it the way you are makes the very existence of the linked list somewhat pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a number of things wrong... but the primary one (that's causing all 0's) is here:

```
        if (v[i]>v[j])
        {
            aux=v[i];
            v[i]=v[j];
            v[j]=v[i];
        }
```

Your swap is incorrect, you store `v[i]`'s data in `aux`, but you never set it to `v[j]`, so you're just overwriting everything with the smallest value (`0`)

You wanted:

```
v[j] = aux;
```

---

The other major issue is you're not keeping track of the "head" of your list:

```
    p=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    q->next=p;
    p->data=v[i];
    p->next=NULL;
    q=p;
```

You keep assigning a new value to `p`, then overwritting `q` with `p`... so there's no way to find your way back. You'll only have the last value in your linked list

Something like:

```
struct Node* head = NULL;
...
head = q=(Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node)); // head points to the first node now
```

Then later:

```
p = head; // reset p to the start of the list.
while (p)
{
    ...
```

Comment: And what should I do to keep track of the `head` ?

Comment: @DanPasca - see the edit. It's just a pointer that doesn't move. It points to the first node you allocate, then whenever you want to go back to the start of the list you set yourself to head.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set up all this array stuff; the fragment below returns a linked list of N=cnt Nodes with random payload:

```
struct Node *getnrandom(unsigned cnt) {
struct Node *p=NULL, **pp;

for (pp=&p; cnt--; pp = &(*pp)->next) {
    *pp = malloc (sizeof **pp);
    if (!*pp) break;
    (*pp)->data = rand();
    }
if (*pp) (*pp)->next = NULL;
return p;
}
```

UPDATE: since the OP appears to need the values to be ordered, he could either perform insertion (at the right position) into the llist (N*N) , or sort it post hoc. (NlogN)